# Facebook Game Development - Which Programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages, facebook

I am going to develop a facebook game as topic for my thesis.

I am wondering which programming languages i should choice.

I am used to programming in .NET. But i am also comfortable in C++ and Java.
I don't want to use Flash as the graphical frontend since i don't like it.

So i guess i'll go with ASP.NET + Silverlight.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds good. Basically - anything that integrates with Facebook goes, and the integration is HTTP based, so - you mostly can use what you prefer.  I would also use your selection.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use Silverlight since it won't work on most computers... But of course if you really want to, then I don't see any real problems with your set of technologies. You even have a nice fbml element to handle it:

> fb:silverlight
>
> Renders a Microsoft
> Silverlight control. On profile pages,
> an image appears first. When the user
> clicks the image, it turns into the
> control. On canvas pages, the image
> does not appear, and the Silverlight
> control is directly included.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:silverlight

Comment: You are right. But Silverlight penetration grwos really fast. Right now 40%-50% of all browsers have installed silverlight.

Comment: @ben: yeah but people using a mobile device/a mac/a linux will not be able to view your app. And 40-50% is still very low...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flex? The graphical front end that can be developed using flex is very cool.

Also, silverlight is another option that you can consider using. Although, for silverlight applications to work on many browsers, you need to install the plugins for those browsers.

The visual and graphical effects that you get using either of the two languages are too good!